# Can I check if Bootstrap Modal Shown / Hidden?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

Can I check if Bootstrap Modal currently Shown / Hidden Programatically?

Like   `bool a = if("#myModal").shown();` ?

I need true/false

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery if statement to check visibility](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616020/jquery-if-statement-to-check-visibility)

Answer (score 147, accepted):

```
alert($('#myModal').hasClass('in'));
```

It will return true if modal is open

Comment: if($('#myModal').hasClass('in')){/*do something*/} best usage. thanks

Comment: for me `$('#myModal').hasClass('show')` works, **Bootstrap V4**

Comment: @Samad it doesn'T work with Bootstrap 4, it does with 3 though. reza's answer works with 4, it does not work with 3...

Comment: @estani Try `if($('.modal.in, .modal.show').length)` for **Bootstrap V2, 3, 4+**

Comment: I have tested this in bootstrap 3 and it works great. Will only return true when the modal is showing, will return false when its in the 'fade' state 

Answer (score 32):

The best method is given in the docs

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  // will only come inside after the modal is shown
});
```

for more info refer http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: Sure, that's the best method for executing a function when the modal appears, but that's different from checking if it's currently shown or hidden, as OP asked. My use-case, for example, is to perform an action on keypress, but only if a certain class of modal is visible. I don't see how this method can be used for that.

Comment: @DHW Couldn't you keep track of whether it's open or closed with those methods?  If shown -> store that it's shown, when hidden -> store that it's hidden. Then you can just reference the relevant variables.

Answer (score 27):

its an old question but anyway heres something i used incase someone was looking for the same thing

```
if (!$('#myModal').is(':visible')) {
    // if modal is not shown/visible then do something
}
```

Comment: This just reads so nicely. Also not dependent on specific class selectors which could prove fragile.

Comment: However, I believe it could return a false positive if it's executed during the showing/hiding animation.

Comment: maybe but even though the function waits till the animation is finished to check if its visible or hidden as this one works the same as using normal css.

Answer (score 9):

All Bootstrap versions:

```js
var isShown = $('.modal').hasClass('in') || $('.modal').hasClass('show')
```

To just close it independent of state and version:

```js
$('.modal button.close').click()
```

---

### more info

Bootstrap 3 and before

```js
var isShown = $('.modal').hasClass('in')
```

Bootstrap 4

```js
var isShown = $('.modal').hasClass('show')
```

Answer (score 6):

When modal hide? we can check like this :

```
$('.yourmodal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    // do something here
})
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's some custom code that gives the modal states more explicitly named classes:

```
$('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e)
{
    e.currentTarget.classList.add("modal-fading-in");
    e.currentTarget.classList.remove("modal-fading-out");
    e.currentTarget.classList.remove("modal-hidden");
    e.currentTarget.classList.remove("modal-visible");
});

$('.modal').on('hide.bs.modal', function(e)
{
    e.currentTarget.classList.add("modal-fading-out");
    e.currentTarget.classList.remove("modal-fading-in");
    e.currentTarget.classList.remove("modal-hidden");
    e.currentTarget.classList.remove("modal-visible");
});

$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e)
{
    e.currentTarget.classList.add("modal-hidden");
    e.currentTarget.classList.remove("modal-fading-in");
    e.currentTarget.classList.remove("modal-fading-out");
    e.currentTarget.classList.remove("modal-visible");
});

$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e)
{
    e.currentTarget.classList.add("modal-visible");
    e.currentTarget.classList.remove("modal-fading-in");
    e.currentTarget.classList.remove("modal-fading-out");
    e.currentTarget.classList.remove("modal-hidden");
});
```

You can then easily target the modal's various states with both JS and CSS.

JS example:

```
if (document.getElementById('myModal').hasClass('modal-fading-in'))
{
    console.log("The modal is currently fading in. Please wait.");
}
```

CSS example:

```
.modal-fading-out, .modal-hidden
{
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `hasClass('in')`. It will return true if modal is in `OPEN` state.

E.g:

```
if($('.modal').hasClass('in')){
   //Do something here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In offical way:

```
> ($("element").data('bs.modal') || {})._isShown    // Bootstrap 4
> ($("element").data('bs.modal') || {}).isShown     // Bootstrap <= 3
```

`{}` is used to avoid the case that modal is not opened yet (it return `undefined`). You can also assign it equal `{isShown: false}` to keep it's more make sense.

Comment: this is what I was after, it already returns `true` while the modal is opening, but before the `shown` class is applied

Answer (score 2):

With Bootstrap 4:

```
if ($('#myModal').hasClass('show')) {
    alert("Modal is visible")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($('.modal').hasClass('in')) {
    alert($('.modal .in').attr('id')); //ID of the opened modal
} else {
    alert("No pop-up opened");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me this works

```
 
if($("#myModal").css("display") !='none' && $("#myModal").css("visibility") != 'hidden')
```

`alert("modal shown");`

Answer (score 0):

I try like this with function then calling if needed a this function. Has been worked for me.

```
function modal_fix() {
var a = $(".modal"),
    b = $("body");
a.on("shown.bs.modal", function () {
    b.hasClass("modal-open") || b.addClass("modal-open");
});
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This resolved your problems, if true no refresh, and false refresh

```js
var truFalse = $('body').hasClass('modal-open');
```