# Capture close event on Bootstrap Modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, events, bootstrap-modal

I have a Bootstrap Modal to select events.
If the user clicks on the X button or outside the modal, I would like to send them to the default event.
How can I capture these events?

This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content event-selector">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
                <center><h1 class="modal-title event-selector-text">Select an Event</h1><center>
            </div>
            <div class="container"></div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="event-banner">
                    <a href="/?event=1">
                        <img src="<?php echo IMAGES_EVENT1_LOGO; ?>" width="100%">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="event-banner">
                    <a href="/?event=2">
                        <img src="<?php echo IMAGES_EVENT2_LOGO; ?>" width="100%">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: $(window).onclick() in javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bind a function to Twitter Bootstrap Modal Close](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363802/bind-a-function-to-twitter-bootstrap-modal-close)

Answer (score 250, accepted):

This is very similar to another stackoverflow article, **[Bind a function to Twitter Bootstrap Modal Close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363802/bind-a-function-to-twitter-bootstrap-modal-close)**.  Assuming you are using some version of Bootstap v3 or v4, you can do something like the following:

```
$("#myModal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {
    // put your default event here
});
```

Comment: that works but how can I differentitate between normal close and a forced close? I have 2 buttons (OK, CANCEL). With cancel I close it from the template but with ok I need to close it first and do my stuff. What I need is a callback, not an event

Answer (score 30):

Though is answered in another stack overflow question [Bind a function to Twitter Bootstrap Modal Close](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13201843/1436594) but for visual feel here is more detailed answer.

Source: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events

[image]

Answer (score 17):

I tried using it and didn't work, guess it's just the modal versioin.

Although, it worked as this:

```
$("#myModal").on("hide.bs.modal", function () {
    // put your default event here
});
```

Just to update the answer =)

Answer (score 10):

[catch close event in bootstrap 5, without jquery](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#events):

```
var myModalEl = document.getElementById('myModal')
myModalEl.addEventListener('hidden.bs.modal', function (event) {
  // do something...
})
```

Comment: It's works fine.

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me, anyone can try it:

```
$("#myModal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {
    for (instance in CKEDITOR.instances)
        CKEDITOR.instances[instance].destroy();
    $('#myModal .modal-body').html('');    
});
```

you can open ckEditor in Modal window

Answer (score 1):

Alternative [way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28454577/10634638) to check would be:

```
if (!$('#myModal').is(':visible')) {
    // if modal is not shown/visible then do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem in a web app using Microsoft Visual Studio 2019, Asp.Net 3.1 and Bootstrap 4.5.  I had a modal form open to add a new staff person (only a few input fields) and the Add Staff button would invoke an ajax call to create the staff records in the database.  Upon successful return the code would refresh the partial razor page of staff (so the new staff person would appear in the list).

Just before the refresh I would close the Add Staff modal and display a Please Wait modal which only had a bootstrap spinner button on it.  What happened is that the Please Wait modal would stay displayed and not close after the staff refresh and the modal('hide') function on this modal was called. Some times the modal would disappear but the modal backdrop would remain effectively locking the Staff List form.

Since Bootstrap has issues with multiple modals open at once, I thought maybe the Add Staff modal was still open when the Please Wait modal was displayed and this was causing problems.  I made a function to display the Please Wait modal and do the refresh, and called it using the Javascript function setTimeout() to wait 1/2 second after closing/hiding the Add Staff modal:

```
//hide the modal form
$("#addNewStaffModal").modal('hide');
setTimeout(RefreshStaffListAfterAddingStaff, 500); //wait for 1/2 second
```

Here is the code for the refresh function:

```
function RefreshStaffListAfterAddingStaff() {
    // refresh the staff list in our partial view

    //show the please wait message
    $('#PleaseWaitModal').modal('show');

    //refresh the partial view
    $('#StaffAccountsPartialView').load('StaffAccounts?handler=StaffAccountsPartial',
        function (data, status, jqXGR) {

            //hide the wait modal
            $('#PleaseWaitModal').modal('hide');
            // enable all the fields on our form
            $("#StaffAccountsForm :input").prop("disabled", false);

            //scroll to the top of the staff list window
            window.scroll({
                top: 0,
                left: 0,
                behavior: 'smooth'
            });

        });
}
```

This seems to have totally solved my problem!

Comment: Sorry, since I first tried this and it worked 5 or 6 times in a row, I recompiled my application and am having the same problem again, the Please Wait modal stays displayed after modal('hide').

Answer (score 0):

```
$("myModal button.close").click(function() {        
      // do something ...
});
```