# Bootstrap(2.3.2) modal popup visibility check

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I need to insert a class name to `body` tag when the bootstrap `pop up` is opened. I have tried adding using jquery but unfortunately it is not working. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code

```
if(!$('.modal-backdrop').is(':visible'))
{
$(body).addClass("test");
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h3WDq/1406/)**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19674701/can-i-check-if-bootstrap-modal-shown-hidden

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if bootstrap modal is open, so i can use jquery validate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19506672/how-to-check-if-bootstrap-modal-is-open-so-i-can-use-jquery-validate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.modal-backdrop').on('shown', function() {
        $('body').addClass("test");
    });

    $('.modal-backdrop').on('hidden', function () {
    $('body').removeClass("test");
})
```

Comment: I personally use this method myself, can be an issue if the modal is faded in and the user is a fast clicker but I find it works alright.

Comment: if($('.modal-backdrop').hasClass('in')){
   $('body').addClass("test");
 }

Comment: But it is not removing the `test` class from body when pop up is closed

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with 'shown' bootstrap event, like so:

```
$('.modal-backdrop').on('shown', function() {
    $('body').addClass("test");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems in your demo the 
     $('#myModal1 .selectpicker').selectpicker();
is causing some problem.

But you could use this code from http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals docs

```
$('#myModal1').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
 $('body').addClass("test");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h3WDq/1410/

Please check via console log if class is added.

Comment: In my case I am not using id names so need to get it done by class names.

Comment: Then you can just change the id to class it will still work. do you have many modals with the same class?

Comment: Yes I have multiple pop ups with different class names so can't specify a tag class and write script for tat, tat is why I need to check with the overlay class which is `.modal-backdrop`

Comment: how about this? http://jsfiddle.net/h3WDq/1410/ since every modal has a .modal class.

Comment: But in my real page I do not have ids so can not refer` #mymodal`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```js
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  // will only come inside after the modal is shown
});
```

Answer (score 0):

plz use bootstrap modal events for this: 
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#js-events

you can use this: `$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e){})`
http://jsfiddle.net/h3WDq/1408/